# C++ - What is wrong with my move/copy constructors and move/copy assign operators?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, move-semantics

So I have my own matrix class and I have tried to overload the `+` and `+=` operators for the class like this:

```
template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::operator+=(Matrix& mat) {
  if (this->m_rows != mat.m_rows || this->m_cols != mat.m_cols) {
    cerr << "Matrix rows/cols don't match" << endl;
  }
  else {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->m_rows; i++) {
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->m_cols; j++) {
        this->m_vec[i * this->m_cols + j] += mat.m_vec[i * this->m_cols + j];
      }
    }
  }
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T> mat1, Matrix<T>& mat2) {
  if (mat1.get_rows() != mat2.get_rows() || mat1.get_cols() != mat2.get_cols()) {
    cerr << "Matrix rows/cols don't match" << endl;
  }
  else {
    mat1 += mat2;
    return mat1;
  }
}
```

(I am attempting to make the `+` operator chainable and the `+=` non-chainable. Matrix is represented by a one-dimensional array)

However, when I try to add two matrices, the program refuses to add them (no error message). I am suspecting that there may be something wrong with either my move/copy constructors, move/copy assignment operators or my destructor, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
// Copy constructor
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix& obj) {
  size_t rows = obj.get_rows();
  size_t cols = obj.get_cols();
  this->m_rows = rows;
  this->m_cols = cols;
  this->m_capacity = rows * cols;
  this->m_vec = new T[rows * cols];
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      this->m_vec[j + i * cols] = obj(i, j);
    }
  }
}

// Move constructor
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix&& obj)
  : m_rows(0)
  , m_cols(0)
  , m_capacity(0)
  , m_vec(nullptr)
{
  m_rows = obj.get_rows();
  m_cols = obj.get_cols();
  m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
  m_vec = obj.m_vec;

  obj.m_rows = 0;
  obj.m_cols = 0;
  obj.m_capacity = 0;
  obj.m_vec = nullptr;
}

// Destructor
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
  delete[] m_vec;
}

// Copy assignment operator
template <class T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(const Matrix& obj)
{
  m_rows = obj.get_rows();
  m_cols = obj.get_cols();
  m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
  m_vec = obj.m_vec;
  return *this;

}

// Move assignment operator
template <class T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix&& obj)
{
  if (this != &obj)
  {
    delete[] m_vec;
    m_rows = obj.get_rows();
    m_cols = obj.get_cols();
    m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
    m_vec = obj.m_vec;

    obj.m_rows = 0;
    obj.m_cols = 0;
    obj.m_capacity = 0;
    obj.m_vec = nullptr;
  }
  return *this;
}

// Matrix class properties
class Matrix{
private:
  size_t m_rows;
  size_t m_cols;
  size_t m_capacity;
  T* m_vec;
}
```

I am quite new to C++ and this is my first time attempting to create copy/move constructors/assignment operators, so there might be something obvious that I am missing. Maybe I am even overcomplicating this. Is there an easier/better way to write move/copy constructors and assignment operators? Are you able to spot anything strange here? It seems fine to me...

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have now tried to change the copy assignment operator as suggested by @eerorika, but my `+` and `+=` operators still don't work (same as before). Just to be sure, I then also tried to edit my move assignment operator and move constructor in the same way as I edited my copy assignment operator and still... nothing. Here are the edited versions

```
// Move constructor
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix&& obj)
  : m_rows(0)
  , m_cols(0)
  , m_capacity(0)
  , m_vec(nullptr)
{
  this->m_rows = obj.get_rows();
  this->m_cols = obj.get_cols();
  this->m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
  //m_vec = obj.m_vec;
  this->m_vec = new T[obj.get_rows() * obj.get_cols()];
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.get_rows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < obj.get_cols(); j++) {
      this->m_vec[j + i * obj.get_cols()] = obj.m_vec[i * this->m_cols + j];
    }
  }

  obj.m_rows = 0;
  obj.m_cols = 0;
  obj.m_capacity = 0;
  obj.m_vec = nullptr;
}

// Move assigment operator
template <class T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix&& obj)
{
  // If the address of the object being passed in is the same as "this", do nothing.
  if (this != &obj)
  {
    delete[] m_vec;
    this->m_rows = obj.get_rows();
    this->m_cols = obj.get_cols();
    this->m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
    //m_vec = obj.m_vec;
    this->m_vec = new T[obj.get_rows() * obj.get_cols()];
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.get_rows(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < obj.get_cols(); j++) {
        this->m_vec[j + i * obj.get_cols()] = obj.m_vec[i * this->m_cols + j];
      }
    }

    obj.m_rows = 0;
    obj.m_cols = 0;
    obj.m_capacity = 0;
    obj.m_vec = nullptr;
  }
  return *this;
}

// Copy assignment operator
template <class T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix& obj)
{
  this->m_rows = obj.get_rows();
  this->m_cols = obj.get_cols();
  this->m_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
  //m_vec = obj.m_vec;
  this->m_vec = new T[obj.get_rows() * obj.get_cols()];
  for (int i = 0; i < obj.get_rows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < obj.get_cols(); j++) {
      this->m_vec[j + i * obj.get_cols()] = obj.m_vec[i * this->m_cols + j];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Any idea of what might be wrong now? Are you sure that there is nothing wrong with the code in my `+` and `+=` operators? Help.

EDIT 2:

Due to a request by @numzero I will add the code for my `operator()`

```
template <class T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) {
  if (row > this->m_rows || col > this->m_cols) {
    cerr << "index out of range" << endl;;
  }
  return this->m_vec[(row - 1) * m_cols + (col - 1)];
}
```

Comment: `operator+`, `operator+=` and copy constructor should get their operands by const references, since they don't modify their operands. Your `operator+` even gets one parameter copied.

Comment: *I try to add two matrices, the program refuses to add them* What does it mean? And there is this attempt in the code above? Please make [mcve].

Comment: @S.M. `operator+` is okay as the copy it gets is the object it modifies and returns. But constness would be nice where appropriate.

Comment: Wait, it’s not okay. No `return` in the `if` branch is UB.

Comment: Your operator += overloading should have the declaration like `T& T::operator +=(const T2& b);`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Recommendation: Strive for [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Try to build around smarter structures so that you don't need the Rule of Three or Five.

Comment: @Mannoj OP said they don't want to allow `operator+=` to be chained.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I missed it; language standard says dont change the meaning while overloading operators

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but those bounds checks shouldn't print an error message and return. They should throw an exception. That's what exceptions are for.

Comment: @Mannoj I don't think the language standard says that. It's just good advice. But you are free to change the meaning of operators, for better or worse. Look at how the bitshift operator was taken over by the standard library for streaming. `std:: cout << "foo"` completely changes the meaning of `<<` which was originally a bitshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy assignment operator copies the `m_vec` pointer, instead of copying its contents (like the copy constructor does).

Comment: Will fixing this have an effect on my code? Or is it just a bad/non-recommended way to write copy assignment operators?

Comment: I have now made your suggested change but no luck. My addition operators still don't work. Read my edit in the post. Got any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Schytheron New move ctor and assignment leak but should work fine otherwise. There must be something wrong in the parts not present in the code you show. How do you test the operators? Also what does `operator()` look like?

Comment: Really simple tests. Let's say I have three matrices `A`, `B` and `C`. If I do `A += B`, the code works fine. But if I do `C = A + B` the program crashes/aborts. Does this indicate that there is something wrong with my `+` operator? Anyway, Ill add the `operator()` code shortly in a second edit (although I don't think there is anything wrong with that one).

Comment: @Schytheron Your operator() is definitely inconsistent with how you use it in the copy ctor. You write `this->m_vec[j + i * cols] = obj(i, j);` (btw `this` is optional there) but `obj(i, j)` is `obj.m_vec[(i - 1) * m_cols + (j - 1)];`. That is, in most places indices start from 0 but `operator()` expects one-based indices. Your program may easily (and silently, on some systems) crash when both `i` and `j` are 0 as in that case, `obj.m_vec[~0 * m_cols + ~0];` is accessed which is likely far away from accessible memory.

Comment: Whoops, miscalculated. On 32-bit systems that would be just before `m_vec` contents, due to modulo arithmetic. But on 64-bit systems things are more complicated due to 32-to-64 bits (unsigned int to size_t) value expansion. Still the resulting value will not be a valid index.

Comment: I tried replacing the right hand side of the inner loop line in my copy constructor with `obj.m_vec[i * cols + j]` (instead of `obj(i, j)`) just to be sure and it worked! I can't believe my `operator()` was broken all along (not broken, but the nature of it caused indexing problems). I have been looking for the problem in the wrong place all along. I can't believe I didn't spot this earlier, it's quite obvious. I feel so stupid now... anyway, thanks for helping me fix the issue. I will accept your answer now :)

Answer (score 4):

> What is wrong with my move/copy constructors and move/**** assign operator<strike>s</strike>?

Nothing serious as far as I can tell. One minor issue is that you unnecessarily assign the members that you could have initialised with those values directly in the member initialiser list.

> What is wrong with my **copy assign** operator<strike>s</strike>?

Your destructor deletes the member pointer. Because of this, you must maintain a class invariant that every instance of the class has unique ownership of the pointer i.e. no other instance has the same pointer value. Otherwise the destructor of the respective objects would attempt to delete the same pointer which results in undefined behaviour.

Your copy assign operator copies the pointer which violates that class invariant. See your copy constructor for an example of what you're supposed to do instead.

---

Bonus advice: Don't ever use owning bare pointers like you do here. Use smart pointers or RAII containers such as `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I understand what you said about the destructor. Are you saying that there is something wrong with my destructor and that I need to change the code or are you just warning me, saying that that is a bad way to write a destructor? Or are, you saying that the problem with the destructor fixes itself if I change the copy assign operator? Btw, I have to use a bare pointer. This is for a school assignment (part of it).

Comment: @Schytheron `Are you saying that there is something wrong with my destructor .` No. I'm saying: because of what you do in the destructor, you must not share the same pointer value across separate objects. That sharing of the pointer value is wrong. You need to fix the copy assignment operator which shares the pointer value.

Comment: "you must not share the same pointer value across separate objects". And I fix that by changing the `m_vec` assignment in my copy assignment operator (in the same way I do it in my copy constructor)? Sorry if my questions are a bit dumb. I am new to C++ and a bit confused. Not sure what "share the same pointer value across separate objects" means exactly or what you're referring to.

Comment: @Schytheron `Not sure what "share the same pointer value across separate objects"` Let's say you have object `a` whose member `a.m_ptr` points to address `x`. If you have another object,`b`, whose member `b.m_ptr` also points to the address `x`, and the destructor of both objects deletes `x`, then `x` is deleted twice. That must not happen.

Comment: Ah, ok... that's kind of what I assume you meant, just wasn't sure. But what are you implying remedies this situation? By fixing the copy assignment operator? That's what I am confused about. I wasn't sure what you were getting at/what I needed to do about the destructor. 

Also, if my copy assignment operator is broken... does that mean my move assignment operator and move constructor are also broken (they also assign `m_vec` in the same way as the copy assignment operator)?

Comment: @Schytheron `By fixing the copy assignment operator? ` Yes. Like I said: *You need to fix the copy assignment operator*. `does that mean my move assignment operator is also broken` No. The move operator does `obj.m_vec = nullptr;` so the objects do not end up with the same value.

Comment: Ah, ok... sorry for the confusion. I get what you're saying now. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have now tried to fix the copy assignment operator as you suggested but no luck. My `+` and `+=` operators still don't work (same as before). I even tried to change the move constructor and move assignment operator in the same way (just to be sure)... nope... still nothing. I have made an edit in my post. Please check it out and see if you spot anything strange... please.